# Website in wordpress redirects to old URL after migration

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I had never done migrating a site on wordpress, I'll put step by step how I did, need to put the site on a new domain that are on the same server, so only the migrated files, the database is equal.

I copied all the files from the old wordpress to the new site folder, 
I had the following result on the new site:
Home - The site carries the theme but a message appears: 404: PAGE OR FILE NOT FOUND.
newsite/wp-admin/ - redirect to oldsite/wp-admin/

I have the option in the site administrator old put the new URL but I'm afraid I could never access. it can go?

Thanks.

Comment: The [documentation on moving a WordPress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) is pretty good. Also, this question is off topic here and more suited on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to make a change to your database.
In the database table wp_options (or whatever your database prefix is), you need to change two lines.

One should be `option_id` 1, `option_name` siteurl. Change the `option_value` from the old url to the new url.

Similarly there should also be `option_id` 36, `option_name` home. Change the `option_value` also from the old url to the new url.

This should do the trick. Also check out http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/08/moving-wordpress-website/ for the best method to migrate.

**Edit**

In the comments Damon also mentions the issue with re-linking all the images. This for sure can be a right pain, but I suggest this plugin.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Just search for the old url and replace with the new one. Before doing this though, make sure you have a backup of the database. You can never guarantee the results when using plugins to mess with your database. But this has always worked for me.

Comment: I changed my siteurl and home in wp_options but still wordpress redirects.

Comment: Please check the search and replace plugin mentioned above in case something else is redirecting ie a plugin you have installed, be sure to backup. You could also disable all plugins before this to check if this is the case. I would also check your .htaccess file and possibly your apache configuration.

Comment: After you've changed those two DB fields, it still might redirect because the browser caches redirects. You can clear your browser cache, or what I do, is open the dev tools, go to network tab, and  check 'disable cache', then try the new url again. (This is in chrome-based browsers, others will likely be similar.) This is what works for me.

Comment: @AaronWallentine you can also open a private tab and test this way.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat yes, any way to clear that redirect cache ... you're right that is simpler, haha

Answer (score 59):

I've solved my issue with my solution at No# 04 See below what I tried:

**1- Make sure Database wp_option links are set**

```
/* MySQL: */
update wp_options set option_value = 'http://example.com' where option_name = 'siteurl';
update wp_options set option_value = 'http://example.com' where option_name = 'home';
```

**2- Additionally define url in wp-config.php file**

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

**3- Clear cache of from server**

***4- Clear your browser cache & history (Hurray!!! it solved my issue no redirection)***

On Chrome, Navigate to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and clear image and file cache.

Comment: #2 pointed me to my issue, wp-config was pointing to my staging DB, which understandably was pointing to the staging URL. Thanks, +1

Comment: After clearing cache, it worked fine but not changed in db; only changed some settings in WP admin settings.

Answer (score 17):

I think i need to give my contribution! In case you are using `Polylang` with a *dynamic IP*, add `define('PLL_CACHE_HOME_URL', false);` in your `wp-config.php` and it will solve all your problems (redirection to the former url)!

Comment: Thanks. that works great, for me that was the missing part even though I don't use Polylang

Comment: Thanks! In my case the problem was this!

Comment: Dear Angel who came down from heaven, thank you for your precious contribution. I was corroding in anguish for the past week and the evil demon of polylang was the problem keeping me from my bright future.

Answer (score 7):

```
define('WP_HOME','domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','domain.com');
```

This goes in your wp-config.php

Also, be sure to clear your cache and use this script to replace ALL urls in your database.

https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Answer (score 2):

If this setting not work:
define('WP_HOME','domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','domain.com');

Try a new browser and clear cache. or try to disable all plugins and check if it working.

Mine worked after i removed cache.

Answer (score 2):

My redirection issue was due to caching. If you do not want to have to clear all your cache and you are using Chrome:

Right click anywhere on the page > `inpect element` > `Network` tab > tick `disable cache`. Then in that same Chrome tab try to load your website again.

Answer (score 0):

STILL if nothing works

GOTO : www.yoursiteurl.com/wp-admin
['YES' IT WILL OPEN , if you have migrated correctly]

GOTO : Settings => General Tab =>

you will see two fields their

1. Wordpress Address URL  - Enter your site URL
2. Site Address URL  - Enter your site URL

Make URLs same in Both fields 
SAVE changes

Enter your site URL in browser clear cache and reload 
Yeahhh.... Worked for me

Enjoy

Dont forget  to modify  WP_Options table with your site URL details.
Take care 
[my site](http://www.pixelsgen.com)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the plugins folder worked for me.

It was one of the redirection plugins that allowed only logged-in visitors to view the shop pages that was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem like my wp-admin was redirecting to the previous domain whenever I log in after migration of the wordpress website. To solve this problem follow these steps:

**It is Simple**

1. Access your **PHPMyAdmin** database
2. Check all tables
3. Replace all irrelevant URL's with your current website URL's
4. Done