# old wordpress website url is still redirecting to my new shopify website?

Tags: wordpress

old website is not accessible anymore I think! There is no hosting for that.

New website is accessible of course.
website is [www.rowingjewellery.com.au](http://www.rowingjewellery.com.au)

old website domain name is [www.strokesidedesigns.com.au](http://www.strokesidedesigns.com.au) ( this is not set as subdomain so rowingjewellery is the main. )
so why this is still redirecting me to my shopify site???

Comment: Before posting a question, it is expected that ***you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to resolve it yourself***. Please read **[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)** and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I would guess the **strokesidedesigns.com.au** domain still contains old nameservers, so it points to the new website.

Removing the nameservers for that domain should prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for old domain records in database and replace them if needed with this tool:

[DB replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Also refresh Permalinks in wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122583/website-in-wordpress-redirects-to-old-url-after-migration) answer

clear your all browser cache and refresh your site. I hope it would be helpful for you